# Unable to downcast from SKPhysicsJoint to SKPhysicsJointPin (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a SpriteKit Project. I access my node's joints through node.physicsBody?.joints.

It should contain one SKPhysicsJointPin and indeed I am getting an array that contains one SKPhysicsJoint object back.

But I'm not able to downcast it from SKPhysicsJoint to SKPhysicsJointPin

```
for joint in (node.physicsBody?.joints)! {
    print("Joint found") // Is executed
    if let myJoint = joint as? SKPhysicsJointPin {
      print("SKPhysicsJointPin object found") // Is not executed
    }
}
```

My created joint is certainly a SKPhysicsJointPin object but my program doesn't execute the second print statement.

why is it not possible to downcast to it?  Did I stumble over a bug?

Thanks

Comment: What does the error actually say?

Comment: I don't get any error. The block that contains the print statement is simply not executed. In my understanding this means that it cannot be downcasted even it should cause SKPhysicsJointPin is a subclass of SKPhysicsJoint (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsJoint_Ref/).

Comment: @bamboofighter that's a lot of assumptions to jump to. Have you added a breakpoint to check the actual type of `joint`?

Comment: What do you see if you insert something like `else {print(joint.dynamicType)}`?

Comment: @PhillipMills It prints "PKPhysicsJointRevolute". Shouldn't it be SKPhysicsJoint as the reference says (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/joints)?

Comment: @Fogmeister it seems the type is "PKPhysicsJointRevolute"

Comment: If im forcing the cast I get Could not cast value of type 'PKPhysicsJointRevolute' (0x109533c08) to 'SKPhysicsJointPin' (0x102c4b6d8)

Answer (score 0):

Yep. `+[SKPhysicsJointPin allocWithZone:]` returns a `PKPhysicsJointRevolute`:

```
             +[SKPhysicsJointPin allocWithZone:]:
000b8bd4         push       ebp                                                 ; Objective C Implementation defined at 0x1817fc (class)
000b8bd5         mov        ebp, esp
000b8bd7         sub        esp, 0x18
000b8bda         call       0xb8bdf
000b8bdf         pop        eax                                                 ; XREF=+[SKPhysicsJointPin allocWithZone:]+6
000b8be0         mov        ecx, dword [ss:ebp+arg_8]
000b8be3         mov        edx, dword [ds:eax-0xb8bdf+objc_cls_ref_PKPhysicsJointRevolute] ; objc_cls_ref_PKPhysicsJointRevolute
000b8be9         mov        eax, dword [ds:eax-0xb8bdf+0x16e5b0]                ; @selector(allocWithZone:)
000b8bef         mov        dword [ss:esp+0x18+var_10], ecx
000b8bf3         mov        dword [ss:esp+0x18+var_14], eax                     ; argument "selector" for method imp___symbol_stub__objc_msgSend
000b8bf7         mov        dword [ss:esp+0x18+var_18], edx                     ; argument "instance" for method imp___symbol_stub__objc_msgSend
000b8bfa         call       imp___symbol_stub__objc_msgSend
000b8bff         add        esp, 0x18
000b8c02         pop        ebp
000b8c03         ret        
                        ; endp
```

This is a class from PhysicsKit (a private framework). In ObjC that doesn't matter because types are whatever we say they are, as long as the objects respond to the right selectors. In Swift, this creates a type mismatch because types aren't just whatever we say they are.

You could likely create a bridge in ObjC to make it work, but you'd probably run into "use of private frameworks" issues. The bridge would look something like this (untested):

```
// Trust me, compiler, this class will exist at runtime
@class PKPhysicsJoinRevolute;

// And hey, here are some methods that I also promise will exist.
@interface PKPhysicsJointRevolute (Bridge)
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat rotationSpeed;
// ...  whatever properties you need ...
@end
```

But like I say, this probably will get you in trouble. So instead, you probably want to make an ObjC wrapper like (untested)

```
@interface MYPinWrapper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) SKPhysicsJointPin *pin;
- (instancetype)initWithPin:(id)pin;
@end

@implementation MYPinWrapper {
- (instancetype)initWithPin:(id)pin {
    _pin = (SKPhysicsJointPin *)pin;
}
@end
```

Then your Swift would look something like:

```
for joint in (node.physicsBody?.joints)! {
    print("Joint found") // Is executed
    let pin = MYPinWrapper(pin: joint).pin // Launder the pin through ObjC
    // ... pin should now work like a pin even though it's really a revolute.
}
```